# Attached behaviour when several controls are affected

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, attachedbehaviors

In an effort to minimize the stuff in our code behind I want convert some of our event logic into attached behaviour. I've read [this article](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/01/attached-behaviours-in-wpf/) and while I want to achieve something similar, I'm unsure how I would proceed if the behaviour affects multiple controls.

An example: Our application features a sidebar that the user can dock to either the left or right side via a button. If the button is triggered our event fires and rearranges the controls accordingly. This is easy enough to do with plain code behind, since I have access to all controls present in the view.

Now, I would add an attached behaviour to that button to handle that case, but I would need access to other controls to change their positioning. Is this possible with attached behaviour (and if so, how?), or is there another possibility or pattern to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, there is nothing in the MVVM methodology that says that code behind cannot be used. The overriding principle in MVVM is to provide the *Spearation of Concerns* that enables us to test the view models separately from the views.

However, your `SideBar` control sounds like it provides UI functionality rather than data manipulation functionality, in which case the view models don't need to know anything about it. Therefore any code that may be in its code behind shouldn't need to be tested along with the view model tests, so it's quite ok for it to be there.

I generally follow this simple rule:

> If a particular view is just a control *that is used in other views* and just provides some small UI functionality, then I put functionality into its code behind instead of a view model.

An example might be a `FeedbackControl` control which just animates user feedback, or controls that simply encompass a few other standard controls for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Code behind is not as bad as coupling between the view-model (or data context) and the view, and it seems that you have exactly that (implemented in the code behind). You should try to uncouple the view-model (or data context) from the view and to do that you need to introduce properties in the view-model that describes the layout (e.g. `DockingPosition`). The view should then use data-binding to these properties and modify the layout accordingly. You will find that triggers and the visual state manager may help here. (As an added benefit you will be able to animate the layout changes for a better user experience.)

If you are successful in doing this you will discover that you can get rid of a lot of code behind (the bad code behind that introduced a lot of coupling). If at this point, you still have some code behind like code to change a text box into a numeric only text box you can refactor this into attached behaviors that make the behavior reusable and able to be used declaratively in the XAML.

Behaviors are attached to a single `DependencyObject` and only rarely should you try to use a behavior to connect multiple controls.